# Uninstall GarageBand '08

Tags: macos, uninstall, garageband

I want to uninstall GarageBand '08 because my 2007 iMac is running low on disk space. So far, I think I can delete these:

- GarageBand app
- Library/Application Support/Garageband/
- Library/Audio/Apple Loops/

Are there any other files I should delete? Also, why is GarageBand only 182 MB on the Mac App Store? Does it count on you having the above files installed, or can I install the new version from scratch later if I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to delete

- `/Library/Audio/Apple Loops`
- `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand`

Note the slash before, it's the Library on your Macintosh HD's root, not the one in your home folder. Beware that this will also include sound effects for iLife and could have unforeseen consequences.

The new GarageBand will require you to download all additional content – the App Store version just provides the basic application if I recall correctly.

Comment: If I leave the "Apple Loops" folder do you think the rest of iLife be OK? And if later I download the new GarageBand on the App Store, I will have the opportunity to reinstall the necessary files from within the app then?

Comment: My installation of GarageBand '11 had a ~500 MB cache folder in `/private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.GarageBand`.

Comment: @woz I'm not a 100% sure, because you're not supposed to remove those files at all. Leaving Apple Loops intact seems like a good idea. As far as I'm concerned, GarageBand will prompt you to download the files.

Comment: @Lri Interesting. Have you ever used it? I can't find such a folder on my machine, but I never really used GarageBand.

Comment: @slhck Not really. Actually it could've been left there by an earlier version of GarageBand as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are apps that'll do the hard work for you :)

[AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (free) or [AppZapper](http://appzapper.com/) (commercial).

Comment: I have AppCleaner, but GarageBand has a lock next to it, preventing you from deleting it.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot about that, I don't have it installed at work. You've covered most of the files in your question. It's not a big file but if you want to remove the preference file its located : /Users/you/Library/Preferences

Comment: Good point. I forgot those.